# Receiving login failed on MongoDB when connecting from Azure but not locally

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, asp.net-core

I have a web application that I created in .net core 3.1.  For the backend, I have a MongoDB, so I am using the MongoDB Driver 2.11.2 to connect to it.

My connection string for connecting to the MongoDB looks like:

`mongodb+srv://{username}:{password}@cluster0.4iltc.azure.mongodb.net/{dbname}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

The problem I have is that when I run the web application locally on my own machine, it connects to the MongoDB without issue, but when I push the site up to Azure, it always returns a 'Login failed for user {username}'.

I've whitelisted the ip addresses of the Azure site in Mongo, but I don't know if I am missing another config option that needs to be set because like I say, it works OK from my local machine, but not from Azure.

Comment: Find out what auth source that is used, and try the non-srv uri. See the note about srv uris in https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-authentication/#auth-source.

Comment: Thanks @D.SM, that appears to just be for the Ruby driver, I am using the C#/.net driver

Comment: The code is, the concepts are not.